# В своей тарелке

Tags: фразеология, цельное-выражение

Попалось в книжке такое выражение ***без отрицания.*** А имеет ли оно право на существование?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-видимому, такое выражение употребимо, но с существенными ограничениями. Оно может подойти к какому-то конкретному контексту в качестве противовеса случившемуся "стандартному" употреблению, как его отрицание в диалоге и т. п. (как "отрицание отрицания").

> — Видимо, он от этого пребывал не в своей тарелке?
>
> — Да нет, вполне себе в своей (тарелке).

Можно себе представить его и в контексте *противопоставления ожидаемому* (не высказанному в явной форме) состоянию неловкости персонажа, но едва ли оно может иметь самостоятельное *утвердительное* значение. Для выражения обратного смысла подходят другие фразеологизмы: "в своей стихии", "как рыба в воде".

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! А как же примеры grizzly?

Comment: Думаю, что пример из Чехова укладывается в моё замечание о противопоставлении ожидаемому; из Достоевкого - тоже, хотя и в меньшей степени. Что касается Тургенева, долго жившего во Франции, то к его языку (как к примеру безупречной русской речи) я отношусь с некоторым скептицизмом (его множественные галлицизмы хорошо известны). Лучшие _прозаики_ - мастера слова для меня - Пушкин и Лермонтов. Допускаю однако, что в прошлом это выражение употреблялось более свободно.

Comment: Спасибо, интересно!)

Comment: @Alex_ander Лермонтов это выражение использует (1831 г.): _На вздор и шалости ты хват И мастер на безделки. И, шутовской надев наряд, Ты был **в своей тарелке**..._ (https://stih.pro/bulgakovu-na-vzdor-i-shalosti-ti-hvat/ot/lermontov)

Comment: А здесь и высказано противопоставление ожидаемому, ведь в шутовском наряде надо бы ощущать себя неловко, "не в своей тарелке".

Comment: Согласна с Вами — так и воспринимается. P. S. Просто хотела подтвердить Ваше мнение, обозначенное в комментарии. Пожалуйста, внесите его в ответ — иногда модераторы изничтожают комментарии... И я с большим удовольствием поддержу Ваши рассуждения.

Comment: @Aer Обращаю Ваше внимание (уже в который раз!) на то, что комментарии, т. н. "последние входящие сообщения",  до адресата (то есть до меня) НЕ ДОХОДЯТ. Я их обнаруживаю — иногда — совершенно случайно.

Answer (score 2):

Мода на это выражение время от времени активизируется, но употреблялось оно всегда, наверное. Вот первые попавшиеся примеры у наших классиков:

Старик доктор совершенно **в своей тарелке**... (Ф.М. Достоевский)

Хорош бывает Вячеслав Илларионович на больших званых обедах, даваемых помещиками в честь губернаторов и других властей: тут он, можно сказать, совершенно **в своей тарелке**. (И.С. Тургенев)

Один только Победимский чувствовал себя **в своей тарелке**. (А.П. Чехов)

Comment: Спасибо, убедительно!

Comment: @grizzly _...употреблялось оно всегда, наверное._ Конечно же, не всегда, а только со второй половины XVIII в. (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/wordhistory/485/%D0%9D%D0%95_%D0%92_%D0%A1%D0%92%D0%9E%D0%95%D0%99_%D0%A2%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%9A%D0%95)

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Я не буквально, конечно :) Но Вы нашли замечательный материал; оформите свою находку, пожалуйста, отдельным ответом, это ценно и интересно.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, за формулировку "замечательный материал" (но он ведь, собственно, всем — немного ищущим — вполне доступен, надо только чуток "порыться").

Answer (score 1):

> А имеет ли оно право на существование?

Я согласен, что выражение имеет очень ограниченную определенным контекстом сферу употребления, но границу эту я формулирую одним словом: ирония. Все, уже данные примеры, вполне вписываются. Кроме разве что цитаты из Тургенева, оговорка "можно сказать" имеет место (чтобы читатели чего лишнего не подумали?), но там автор в общем-то тоже немного иронизирует.

То, что принадлежность разговорного стиля, понятно без комментария. Но речь идет именно об иронии, в каком-то серьезном, трагическом или просто грустном повествовании представить невозможно. То, что это именно ирония вытекает из того, что без аллюзии на исходную форму идиомы ("не в своей тарелке") понять смысл невозможно.

Сравните: (не) солоно хлебавши (правда, тут еще спорно слитное/раздельное написание), (не) от хорошей жизни, ростом (не) вышел - ну никак без отрицания полноценной идиомой не воспринимается.

Comment: Точно, спасибо!